# traffic routed without proxychains

Tags: kali-linux, proxy

Before i am encountering problem with Proxychains and Tor in Kali Linux 2 as it seems that traffic to 127.0.0.1:9050 is always denied.

However, when i try to curl my ip (without proxychains), the IP was not mine but one of the tor exit node.

It is the same if i open iceweasel and try to find my ip through whatismyip.net, not my public ip address.
Even after my traffic routed through tor node exit, i can't open my country censored website (reddit is blocked in my country) i am not sure why.

My questions are:
1. Am i now actually behind proxy? if it so, how come i can't access censored websites even after tor proxy?
2. Do anyone know what caused this? because to achieve similar result i need to use proxychains before.